# aws_s3.query_export_to_s3 PostgreSQL RDS extension custom delimiter

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3

I have enabled this extension on my instance and I would like to use a custom delimiter, such as a non-insert character like an ASCII, is it possible ? from the  [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#:%7E:text=Specifies%20the%20character%20that%20separates%20columns%20within%20each%20row%20(line)%20of%20the%20file.%20The%20default%20is%20a%20tab%20character%20in%20text%20format%2C%20a%20comma%20in%20CSV%20format.%20This%20must%20be%20a%20single%20one%2Dbyte%20character.%20This%20option%20is%20not%20allowed%20when%20using%20binary%20format.) says only one-byte characters can be used, any ideas ?

I have tried with characters like `123` or things like that it goes into error, I expect there is a way to be able to insert a special character that in my case is not contained within the extraction

Comment: ASCII characters **are** a one-byte characters in most encodings. Certainly in the de-facto standard UTF-8. Show your full command and the error message please.

Comment: ERROR: COPY delimiter must be a single one-byte

Comment: So show the full command incl. the declared delimiter. And your setting for `'server_encoding'`.

Comment: Thansk for you help but should be resolved adding `DELIMITER E''\t'' '`